# AttributeError: 'NumpyArrayIterator' object has no attribute 'classes'

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I get this error:

AttributeError: 'NumpyArrayIterator' object has no attribute 'classes'

I am trying to make a confusion matrix to evaluate the Neural Net I have trained. I am using ImageDatagenerator and datagen.flow functions for before the fit_generator function for training.

For predictions I use the predict_generator function on the test set. All is working fine so far. Issue arrises in the following:

```
test_generator.reset()
pred = model.predict_generator(test_generator, steps=len(test_generator), verbose=2)

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix, cohen_kappa_score

y_pred = np.argmax(pred, axis=1)

print('Confusion Matrix')
print(pd.DataFrame(confusion_matrix(test_generator.classes, y_pred)))
```

I should be seeing a confusion matrix but instead I see an error. I ran the same code with sample data before I ran on the actual dataset and that did show me the results.

Comment: If I understand well, you want to make confusion_matrix of test_generator classes and predicted (y_pred) classes?

Comment: Yes please. Confusion matrix of truth and predicted values.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to extract labels from generator and then put them in confusion_matrix function. 
 To extract labels use `x_gen,y_gen = test_generator.next()`, just pay attention that labels are one hot encoded.
 
 Example:

```
test_generator.reset()
pred = model.predict_generator(test_generator, steps=len(test_generator), verbose=2)

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix, cohen_kappa_score

y_pred = np.argmax(pred, axis=1)

x_gen,y_gen = test_generator.next()
y_gen = np.argmax(y_gen, axis=1)

print('Confusion Matrix')
print(pd.DataFrame(confusion_matrix(y_gen, y_pred)))
```

Comment: That gives me the following error:

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [32, 8871]

y_gen should also be 8871.